# C++ Trying to add >> Operator Overload To Template

Tags: c++, templates, abstract

I have a class `IPrintable` which is a template and  a class which derives from it - `Date`. I want to add the operator `>>` to the template but keep getting an error:

```
source.cpp(16): error C2259: 'Date': cannot instantiate abstract class
source.cpp(16): note: due to following members:
source.cpp(16): note: 'void IPrintable<Date>::toIs(std::istream &)': is abstract
iprintable.h(19): note: see declaration of 'IPrintable<Date>::toIs'
```

I have successfully added the `<<` operator to the template this way:

```
virtual void toOs(ostream& os) const = 0;
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const IPrintable& toPrint) {
    toPrint.toOs(output);
    return output;
}
```

And then I have declared `virtual void toOs(ostream& os) const = 0;` to `date.h` and implemented it in `date.cpp`.

This is my **IPrintable.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class IPrintable {
private:


public:

    virtual void toOs(ostream& os) const = 0;
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const IPrintable& toPrint) {
        toPrint.toOs(output);
        return output;
    }

    virtual void toIs(istream& input) = 0;
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, IPrintable& toSet) {
        toSet.toIs(input);
        return input;
    }

};
```

This is the declaration of in **Date.h**, under `public`:

```
virtual void toOs(ostream& output) const;
virtual void toIS(istream& input);
```

This is the implementation of the `<<` (`toOs`) and `>>` (`toIs`) in **Date.cpp**:

```
void Date::toOs(ostream& output) const {
    if (!isLeapYear(this->getDay(), this->getMonth(), this->getYear())) {
        cout << "Not a leap year";
        return;
    }
    output << getDay() << "/" << getMonth() << "/" << getYear();
}

void Date::toIS(istream& input) {
    int index;
    string str;
    input >> str;
    index = str.find('/');
    this->setDay(stoi(str.substr(0, index)));
    str = str.substr(index + 1);
    index = str.find('/');
    this->setMonth(stoi(str.substr(0, index)));
    str = str.substr(index + 1);
    this->setYear(stoi(str));
}
```

Please, if any more information is needed please let me know and I will do my best to provide it.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I am sitting on it for so long, I haven't seen it... Guess I needed a fresh eye. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Date::toIS` has a capital S, while your `IPrintable::toIs` does not. If you add `override` to the declaration of `Date::toIS`, you would see that it doesn't actually override anything.